Mechanical linkage to tilt a monitor around an edge
I am not an mechanical engineer, but would need a construction to attach a monitor to a wall and be able to tilt the monitor around the lower edge of the frame.
I want to achieve, that the rotating point is fix in space. Unfortunately, I cannot set a hinge at this position, so I thought there is probably a fancy linkage to allow this, but I have no clue how to search for this.
It shall allow to tilt the monitor around 45° to the front (and if possible 15° to the back).
The monitor (in image: blue) has a VESA 200x200 assembly (green) at the center, where the construction would be attached to. The absolute distance to the wall is not important.
Has someone an idea, how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot!

The monitor is 60cm tall and 10cm thick.

some of the european cabinet hinges may have a similar motion path ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=european+hinges&iax=images&ia=images

two servo motors with lead screws might do the job ... just a thought,  not an answer

@jsotola thanks for the ideas. Just checked all hinges in my apartment, but could not find a similar motion path. But I will check.
True, if I cannot find a "simple" mechanics, I could try to solve it with two mechanics, that are driven by an electronic to mimic the desired behaviour.
Still I would prefer one mechanics.

While playing  around, I stumbled over the "Wyrd Elephant Compliant Mechanism".
When playing with the length of the bars, I get close to what I want.
link

3 points on a circle constrain it.  You can always try to put it on a track that constrains it as you wish. If the track must reside behind the monitor rather than beside it, you have some telescoping annoyances to work out which may make a linkage based system more attractive.

You can use a linkage simulator to verify any design.

If you can allow the pivot point to move a bit with motion, then create a 4-bar linkage where the two support arms intersect at the virtual pivot point.


I found s olution using two linkages. The length of the parallel links have to be the same as the distance of connection monitor to rotation point.
The lengths of the two connecting links have to be the same.
The position of the anchor points has to be on the same level as the rotation point.

